# Change django per-group permissions on the fly

Tags: python, django, permissions

Let's say we have a user, that belongs to two groups, `drivers` and  `receptionists`. We also have a model `Reservation.`

Now, `drivers` have the following permissions:

- `can_edit_reservation`
- `can_view_reservation`

`receptionists` have these permissions:

- `can_edit_reservation`
- `can_view_reservation`
- `can_create_reservation`

What I want to do, is allow a user to switch between groups on the fly when he logs into application. I want to display a dropdown of all the groups that user belogs to (in this case `drivers` and `receptionists`) so when he'd click on `drivers` he'd only have permissions for that group(so only `can_edit_reservation` and `can_view_reservation`) because at the moment user has combined permissions from all groups he belongs to.

I'm not sure what is the best of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The idea of groups is not to make the user choose his permissions but to give permission to the user. Please explain how security and/or the user benefit from your approach.

Comment: I want to allow the user to choose whether he is logged in as `driver` or `receptionist` meaning I want to allow only a subset of rules in that group to be applied.

Comment: That is what you have explained already. But what is the purpose of that? What is the benefit?

Comment: Hm..sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. The application requires that a user can log in under different group and I've decided to use Django groups for that.. Because a user can be both driver or receptionist and when he creates a reservation i need to know if he created it as driver or receptionist. This is where the I'd use the group.